# How to Update github password using command line with no access to credential manager via control panel?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, updates, change-password

While trying to execute "git pull" command, it gives -

> remote: Invalid username or password.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://( my repository url).git/'

I have updated my domain password for my windows credentials due to update policy by my employer. We use the domain credentials for accessing GitHub as well. I suspect this is due to mismatch of passwords in my machine and GitHub. I am unable to update my password from command line and I don't have access to credential manager in control panel.

Could anyone help me with a way to update GitHub password from command line itself?

Comment: Git uses credential helpers to do the work of caching passwords, but there's not really a process in place to help delete that credential.  In this case, it's probably best to work with Credential Manager correctly (at least in the best way that you can).  I'm not sure if it's present on your Windows machine, but you could look at the [cmdkey](https://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html) executable and use that to list the cached credentials and delete the appropriate entries.  Sorry there isn't a better answer here.  You could have your admin help too, or disable the wincred helper and use ssh-keys.

Comment: Thanks @John Szakmeister for your direction, I was able to open credentials manager via command line with ` ‘rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr’  and edit the github password. I saved it and now I am able to run my git commands.

Comment: Great!  Glad you were able to fix it!  FWIW, I think simply deleting the credential would have worked too, and the credential helper would have asked you for the new password.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the issue in https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/793 and related possible duplicate issues.  I added my experience at https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/793#issuecomment-572999326 referencing the fix I used, from https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/817#issue-390940917.

If you upgraded Git Credential Manager for Windows (directly or as part of Git for Windows), and you since then had to change your password, and your server uses NTLM authentication, you may get this error.  The above fix should solve the problem for all repos on the same server, for all future password changes.  Just deleting your stored credentials will give you the same problem again the next time your password changes (according to one of my colleagues).

It looks like this was caused by https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/pull/547 which looks like it was scheduled to be in from release 1.15 of GCMW (March 9th 2018).